# How to get the order number of an object element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, discord.js

I just want to ask how to get the order number of an object element, like:

```
{ '411510958020624384': 272216, <- 0
  '482286641982078977': 195951, <- 1
  '469176984086380574': 156025, <- 2
  '560134275538747403': 126684, <- 3
  '389078110571724801': 101750, <- 4
  '593157035499978752': 66255 } <- 5
```

For example `obj['411510958020624384']` will give you `0`, `obj['560134275538747403']` will give you `3`, and...

How can I do that? ~and thx.

Comment: Object. It is an unordered collection of properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. Object keys are unordered.

Support was more or less fixed in ECMAScript 2015, but it's still unreliable. It's far, *far* better to use an array that you sort, or an array of objects like below:

```js
const keys = [{'411510958020624384':272216},{'482286641982078977':195951},{'469176984086380574':156025},{'560134275538747403':126684},{'389078110571724801':101750},{'593157035499978752':66255}];

const getIndex = (arr, key) => keys.findIndex(({ [key]: k }) => k);

console.log(getIndex(keys, "411510958020624384"));
```

Comment: Actually will be ordered in this case since keys are numeric

Comment: Yes @charlietfl, but the unordered-ness of objects generally still stands.

Comment: Right...whatever order OP hoped for will get replaced by sort order

Comment: My node.js version doen't have this function :/

Comment: What function? `getIndex`?

Comment: (node:4855) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: obj.findIndex is not a function

Comment: nvm, I have an array for that, I will ask another question about it, in json you can easily get the value by string, but not in arrays, so this is a problem.